# automating, "opening a windows app and logging in" with python; which module?

Tags: python, automation, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to write a script that automates opening a windows software and then type the login information (username and password) to fully open said software. Ideally, I would like these actions to be automated to run daily at a certain time. 
 An example of such a software would be Skype but there are many other softwares that I want to try this one.

I'm looking for suggestions for which modules I should look into.

I have been browsing python automation tutorials on youtube  any the only thing I came upon was the module Pywinauto.  Most of the tutorials seem to be focused on opening notepad and using notepad specific commands, so I"m not sure how much freedom I have with other windows applications. I visited the Pywinauto offical site, but the homepage wasn't as detailed as I hoped.

I may plan to automate some more down the road ( executing some commands down  after opening a program), so ideally I want a module that has a lot of flexiblity.

I'm looking for general suggestions and recommendations for modules.

Thanks!

Comment: which program do you want to automate the use of?

Comment: Hi, first I would like to automate opening "Skype" and logging in. After that I would like to try opening "Line" (a program similar to Skype) and logging in, and then make a call.

Comment: If you're going to automate complicated scenarios I'd recommend you [the Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) which introduces how to deal with different accessibility technologies using pywinauto. There is an example for `explorer.exe` on GitHub repo readme also.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yeah, I plan to play around with automation to see the limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for opening programs there is `os.system` and `subprocess.call` some people also use `win32api`.

```
import os
os.system('notepad.exe')

import win32api
win32api.WinExec('notepad.exe')

import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['notepad.exe'])
```

subprocess is "cross-platform".

```
import subprocess
program = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Skype\\Phone\\skype.exe'
subprocess.Popen(program)
```

this opens skype already, so the first step is done.

Next you want to interract with skype. `win32api` is windows only but ill use it for this example. If you save the login in skype, you can already save the login, press enter, put in the password and press enter again. We do this with keyboard commands. Here is a working example which opens skype and logs you in automatically

```
import subprocess
import win32api
import win32com.client
program = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Skype\\Phone\\skype.exe'
subprocess.Popen(program)
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
win32api.Sleep(5000)
shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
win32api.Sleep(6000)
shell.SendKeys("tsadfdsgr")
shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: Wow. This is really helpful. I'm going to read up the docs on win32api and see what else I can do. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hard-coded sleeps and clicks by coordinates is not a reliable way if environment (theme, screen resolution etc.) is intended to change. But for daily tasks on the dedicated machine it might be OK. Anyway Skype or some other messendgers can be automated with more readable code. Will write some examples using pywinauto when I have a chance. Win32 API is just one of the technologies under the hood in pywinauto (MS UI Automation is more powerful and supported since 0.6.0).

Comment: Yeah, I just realized hard-coded sleeps throw off the login process when the program loads too slowly. Does pywinauto introduce  more reliable methods to navigate a program? I look forward to your code. Thank you so much.

Comment: the business-way to do automation properly is having a server where your programs communicate with API's of applications you need to interact with. take a look at `SkPy` for that matter. If you automate your own dailytasks, you don't need to go so far. If you want to automate 1000 processes per hour, well then you cant have it run on a desktop pc on your desk ;)

Comment: Thanks. I'm mainly just going to play around with automation for personal use.  I have a question regarding your answer.  I'm still new to programming, so now sure if there is more cleaner way to press Tab many times but I'm using this `for i in range(4):
    shell.Sendkeys('{TAB}')`